# .each() in Jquery not returning result

Tags: jquery, each

Im having an issue getting the return result when using the .each() method.

here is my code:

```
$(".fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__column-wrapper").each(function(){
      const $contentId = $('.fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__column-wrapper').attr("id");
      const $contentBody = $('#'+ $contentId + '.fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__column-wrapper').find(".body-section__main")
      const $contentBodyArrow = $('.fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__column-wrapper').find(".icon.icon--angle-thin")
      const $contentBodyBtn = $(".fad-btn__toggle",context)  

      if($contentBody.length >=0){
          console.log($contentId)  
          $contentBodyBtn.on('click', function toggleViewmore(e){
             $contentBodyBtn.toggleClass("btn-active");
             if($contentBodyBtn.hasClass("btn-active")){
               $contentBody.addClass("active")
               $contentBodyArrow.addClass("caret-up")
               $contentBodyBtn.text("View less")
             }else{
               $contentBody.removeClass("active")
               $contentBodyArrow.removeClass("caret-up")
               $contentBodyBtn.text("View more")
             }
          }) 
       }
  })
```

Actual result:

```
<div id="01" class="col-sm-9 fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__column-wrapper">
<div id="01" class="col-sm-9 fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__column-wrapper">
```

Desired result:

```
<div id="01" class="col-sm-9 fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__column-wrapper">
<div id="02" class="col-sm-9 fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__column-wrapper">
```

i'd using a index on the backend to get the value in the attribute id. that should also be return in the loop.

here a screenshot of the snippet below:

Comment: could you post a snippet of your html ?

Comment: here is a screenshot of the snippet. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG0Y2.png

Comment: So you are expecting each element to have a unique id? Is that the case with `console.log($contentId)`? How is the id initially set?

Comment: the id is set on the backend side. Im trying to get the loop to iterate over properly, so that the unique id can be targeted in the loop controlling the elements. - EternalHour

Comment: Then you need to fix the ids on the backend first, seems they are the same. Other than that it's not clear what you are trying to do.